# convergency of a function series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I've got the following function series:

$$ f(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{nx}-1}{2^ne^{nx}}$$

Is it punctually convergent and uniformly convergent?

---

What I have done is:

I've chosen the series $\frac{1}{2^n}$ which is bigger than the series given in the problem, and because of the theory of Weierstrass, I've said that as $\frac{1}{2^n}$ is convergent, the given series is also convergent punctually and uniformly.
But I'm not sure this is OK. If it's not, how can I do it?

Comment: For future reference I'd suggest using LaTeX to display equations. Here's a basic tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: It is fine.  $\left|\frac{e^{nx}-1}{2^ne^{nx}}\right|\le \frac1{2^n}$ for $x\in [0,\infty)$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{2^n}=2$.  So, The M-test guarantees uniform convergence on $[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this can be put into the form of a geometric series s.t.

$$f(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^n - \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \bigg(\frac{1}{2e^x}\bigg)^n $$

The first term can be evaluated without thought via the equation for the geometric series: $\sum_\limits{n =0}^{\infty} ar^k = \frac{a}{1-r}$, $\forall |r|<1$,

$$\implies f(x) = 2 - \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \bigg(\frac{1}{2e^x}\bigg)^n$$

The second term is also in the form of a geometric series, however it is only convergent if $\bigg|\frac{1}{2e^x} \bigg| < 1$.

More work is still require, but can you take it from here?